# I want sum of all the elements in a group when using group by

Tags: mysql, sql

Here is my query:

```
SELECT * FROM expense e JOIN category c ON e.category_id = c.category_id WHERE e.id = 42;
```

here is resultset
[image]

I want all the row in category_name look like this

```
category_name       expense_amount
bills and recharge  200
shoes               1200
entertainment       2690
healthcare          726
Utensils            360
travel              1500
food                400
```

Comment: Do you want a php answer based on your existing code or do you want to aggregate in the sql query? If the latter review https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/aggregate-functions.html and post code with sample data if you get into difficulty.

Answer (score 2):

```sql
SELECT *, sum(e.expense_amount)
  FROM expense e
  JOIN category c ON e.category_id = c.category_id
 WHERE e.id = 42
 GROUP BY e.category_id;
```

You would have to use `group by` and a `sum` function to achieve what you are looking for. You can go through the demo below

https://dbfiddle.uk/lrKlt5wM